# How to add custom input via PHP into every Gravity Form?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I need to add custom text input into every Gravity Form on site (captcha-like) via PHP.
And I should throw error if user submitted bad answer into this input.

Is it possible to do it in Gravity Forms?
If yes - what filters should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but if the goal is anti-spam or anti-bot protection, simply use the built-in honeypot from Gravity Forms.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/form-settings/

Otherwise, I believe you want the `gform_pre_render` hook. This is executed before the form is displayed and can be used to manipulate the form object directly.

More info on Gravity Forms' documentation site https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_pre_render/